# can linq expression be case insensitive

Tags: c#, linq, comparison, expression

i am leveraging [this project to use jqgrid to filter and sort collections](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/aspnet/AspNetMVCandJqGrid.aspx).  The one missing feature is that this example is not doing case insensitive search which i need.

So if a user types in "Test" i want it to match with "TEST", "TeST", etc . .

i have code that looks like this:

```
            case WhereOperation.Equal:
                condition = Expression.Equal(memberAccessToString, filter);
                lambda = Expression.Lambda(condition, parameter);
                break;
            case WhereOperation.NotEqual:
                condition = Expression.NotEqual(memberAccessToString, filter);
                lambda = Expression.Lambda(condition, parameter);
                break;
            case WhereOperation.Contains:
                condition = Expression.Call(memberAccessToString,
                    typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains"),
                    Expression.Constant(value));
                lambda = Expression.Lambda(condition, parameter);
                break;
```

is there anyway to have these checks below being case insensitive  so "Test" would equal "TEST"

```
Expression.NotEqual    
Expression.Equal
Expression.Call(memberAccessToString,
                    typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains"),
```

Comment: question is (even if it were possible) why would you need that? There seems to be a design problem - can you elaborate?

Comment: @BrokenGlass - i am using this code to filter collections by some user input.  there is no design problem here.  The user might type in "test" or "test"

Comment: Would calling `ToLower` on both the filter string as well as the filtered value (maybe by using Expression.Call) be an option?

Comment: Couldn't you always format the user input to lowercase and then do the comparison?

Comment: @Heinzi - maybe but i don't fully follow how this would work . .

Comment: @ooo: I've added an example as an answer.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Unfortunately the BCL does not have a `Contains` overload that allows you to specify case invariance.  You will have to grab the correct overload of `IndexOf` as a workaround (checking to see if the result of `IndexOf` is greater than zero):

```
var methodInfo 
    = typeof(string)
        .GetMethod("IndexOf", 
            new[] { typeof(string), typeof(StringComparison) });
```

This `MethodInfo` accepts a `string` and a `StringComparison` which will allow you to specify `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase` if you wish.

Comment: @Andrew Hare - can you clarify your answer.  i am a bit confused by your ressponse . . how would your code below do a case insensitive search ??

Comment: @ooo: I was just writing up an answer, but since Andrew has covered the most important bit, here's the rest of it: var callEx = Expression.Call(memberAccessToString, method,
                                Expression.Constant(value),
                                Expression.Constant(StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));

condition = Expression.NotEqual(callEx, Expression.Constant(-1));

Comment: @Ani - where are you getting "method" from ??

Comment: @ooo: That's the `methodInfo` from Andrew's answer.

Comment: @ooo - Sorry, it wouldn't.  This code just gives you the `MethodInfo` you would need to do a case-invariant "contains" implementation yourself.

Comment: @Ani - Thanks for adding that :) Sorry I renamed the variable on you.

Comment: Actually, I should have been the one to check if the variable was named the same. :) Anyway, feel free to put this into the answer if you want, although you should know I haven't tested it.

Comment: @ooo: As I mentioned in an earlier comment, `condition = Expression.NotEqual(callEx, Expression.Constant(-1));` where `callEx` is what you just posted.

Comment: @Andrew Hare / @Ani - Indexof() doesn't do Equals() but rather Contains() . . is there a different method i should be using to get an exact equals

Comment: @ooo: Yes,  `first.Equals(second, StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase)`

Comment: @Ani - thanks.  can you clarify how i would use the solution in your last comment with the above answer ??

Comment: @ooo: Since the signature is the same as what Andrew has posted, just replace `"IndexOf"` with `"Equals"` in the `GetMethod` call. As for the condition, do `Expression.Equal(callEx, Expression.Constant(true))`

Comment: @Ani - i tried that but i am getting an exception "AmbiguousMatchException" Ambiguous match found.  I assume this is because "Equals" is overloaded . .  any thoughts ??

Comment: Just a note - this will work with regular linq, but not linq to sql or linq to entities.  You will get the error "LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 IndexOf(System.String, System.StringComparison)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression."

Answer (score 20):

You could convert both values to lowercase before doing the comparison. Here's an example for `Contains`:

```
case WhereOperation.Contains:
    var toLower = Expression.Call(memberAccessToString,
                                  typeof(string).GetMethod("ToLower", System.Type.EmptyTypes));
    condition = Expression.Call(toLower,
                                typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains"),
                                Expression.Constant(value.ToString().ToLower()));
    lambda = Expression.Lambda(condition, parameter);
    break;
```

Note, however, that this [won't pass the Turkey test](https://blog.codinghorror.com/whats-wrong-with-turkey/).

Answer (score 4):

You get it following way:

First Extend string class:

```
internal static class StringExtensions

    {
        public static bool ContainsExt(this String str, string val)
        {
            return str.IndexOf(val, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase) > -1 ? true : false;
        }
    }
```

Now write Expression call as

```
Expression.Call(null,
                    typeof(StringExtensions).GetMethod("ContainsExt", new Type[] { typeof(String), typeof(String) }),
                    new[] { memberAccessToString, Expression.Constant(value));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
case WhereOperation.Contains:
     var callEx = Expression.Call(memberAccess, typeof(string).GetMethod("IndexOf", new[] { typeof(string), typeof(StringComparison) }), Expression.Constant(value), Expression.Constant(StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));
     condition = Expression.NotEqual(callEx, Expression.Constant(-1));
     lambda = Expression.Lambda(condition, parameter);
     break;
```