# case insensitive dynamic search for linq to entities

Tags: .net, linq

For the [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5305526/can-linq-expression-be-case-insensitive) , the answer suggests that we cannot use the LINQ to SQL or linq to entities.

If I write

```
Expression toLower = Expression.Call(memberAccess, typeof(T).GetMethod("IndexOf",
                                     new[] { typeof(T), typeof(StringComparison) }));
  Expression  condition = Expression.Call(toLower,
                                typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains"),
                                Expression.Constant(value.ToString().ToLower()));
                    lambda = Expression.Lambda(condition, parameter);
```

I get error:

```
Value cannot be null. Parameter name: method
```

If I write

```
Expression toLower = Expression.Call(memberAccess, typeof(string).GetMethod("IndexOf",
                                         new[] { typeof(string), typeof(StringComparison) }));
```

The error I get is:

```
Incorrect number of arguments supplied for call to method 'Int32 IndexOf(System.String, System.StringComparison)'
```

Thanks in advance

**Edit:**
Here is the snippet and I need to be able to do a case insenstivie filter:

```
public static IQueryable<T> Where<T>(this IQueryable<T> query,
            string column, object value, WhereOperation operation)
        {
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(column))
                return query;

            ParameterExpression parameter = Expression.Parameter(query.ElementType, "p");

            MemberExpression memberAccess = null;
            foreach (var property in column.Split('.'))
                memberAccess = MemberExpression.Property
                   (memberAccess ?? (parameter as Expression), property);

            //change param value type
            //necessary to getting bool from string
            ConstantExpression filter = Expression.Constant
                (
                    Convert.ChangeType(value, memberAccess.Type)
                );

            //switch operation
            Expression condition = null;
            LambdaExpression lambda = null;
            switch (operation)
            {
                //equal ==
                case WhereOperation.Equal:
                    condition = Expression.Equal(memberAccess, filter);
                    lambda = Expression.Lambda(condition, parameter);
                    break;
                //not equal !=
                case WhereOperation.NotEqual:
                    condition = Expression.NotEqual(memberAccess, filter);
                    lambda = Expression.Lambda(condition, parameter);
                    break;
                //string.Contains()
                case WhereOperation.Contains:
                    condition = Expression.Call(memberAccess,
                        typeof(string).GetMethod("Contains"),
                        Expression.Constant(value));
                    lambda = Expression.Lambda(condition, parameter);
                    break;
            }


            MethodCallExpression result = Expression.Call(
                   typeof(Queryable), "Where",
                   new[] { query.ElementType },
                   query.Expression,
                   lambda);

            return query.Provider.CreateQuery<T>(result);
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Modified the code to:

```
   Expression  toLower = Expression.Call(memberAccess, "ToLower", null, null);                  
   lambda = Expression.Lambda(condition, parameter);
```

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to call `IndexOf` without specifying any arguments. You're then trying to use the result as the target of a `Contains` call, which is somewhat odd... I suspect you really want:

```
Expression indexOf = Expression.Call(memberAccess, "IndexOf", null,
                        Expression.Constant(value.ToString()),
                        Expression.Constant(StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase));

Expression condition = Expression.NotEqual(indexOf, Expression.Constant(-1));

lambda = Expression.Lambda(condition, parameter);
```

If you could give us more information about what you're trying to achieve - preferably with a short but complete program - it would be easier to help you.

EDIT: It would make more sense to use `Where` in a compile-time safe way, like this:

```
Expression<Func<T, bool>> lambda = null;

...

lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(condition, parameter);
return query.Where(lambda);
```

Comment: I added the code, The suggestion that you gave, gives compile time errors.

Comment: @Priya10: I've edited the answer now - I'd missed off an argument. But It's odd to call `Where` by reflection like that. Will edit for that too...

Comment: I got an error : LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 IndexOf(System.String, System.StringComparison)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: @Priya10: Okay, so Entity Framework doesn't support that method. It's usually worth testing this sort of thing with a hard-coded LINQ query (converted by the compiler into expression trees) before trying to convert it into manually-generated expression tree yourself. I thought you'd already done that... so I don't know what your overall goal is, but you've now managed to get the expression tree I believe you were aiming for - it just isn't supported :(

Comment: ohh you mean to say, it cannot be done. Do you have any reference, that can be used for generic query build using linq and that gives case insensitive filter

Comment: @Priya10: I'm saying it apparently can't be done that way. I don't know of a way of doing it in EF, I'm afraid.

Comment: Also, I could try return query.Where(lambda); , as it gives compile time error.

Comment: @Priya10: Please, whenever you say "it gives compile time error" you should say *what* error. It should be fine though, if you've changed the declaration of `lambda` as I showed.

Comment: sorry about that, the error is: 'System.Linq.IQueryable<T>' does not contain a definition for 'Where' and the best extension method overload 'System.Linq.Queryable.Where<TSource>(System.Linq.IQueryable<TSource>, System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<TSource,bool>>)' has some invalid arguments and Argument 2: cannot convert from 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<T,bool>>>' to 'System.Linq.Expressions.Expression<System.Func<T,bool>>'

Comment: @Priya: It sounds like you changed the declaration of `lambda` from what I'd got to `Expression<Expression<Func<T, bool>>>` - I've fixed the call to `Expression.Lambda`; it should work now.

Comment: it still gives runtime error: LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Int32 IndexOf(System.String, System.StringComparison)' method, and this method cannot be translated into a store expression.

Comment: @Priya10: Yes, it was never going to fix that problem. I was just fixing the compile-time problem.